# PyMysql ignore warning for cursor

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

There is a problem where I have not been successful no matter how hard I tried. PyMysql does not ignore errors and terminates the loop. My table has to be unique key so I just have to make it bypass this error. Another alternative is to check if the `request_id` already exists, but that's not a good idea. I tried using `cur._defer_warnings` = True` but it didn't work, Please help with solution

```
pymysql.err.IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry 'e27d72a3e0cb7390389671ff3f0ea578' for key 'request_id'")
```

- 

```
try:
    
    cur = connection.cursor()
    
    cur._defer_warnings = True
    
    with cur as cursor:
        
        with open("logs.json", 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as file:
        
            for line in file:
                
                json_line = line.strip()
                
                if is_json(json_line):
                    json_data = line.strip()
                    json_logs = json.loads(json_data)

                    request_id = json_logs['request_id']

                    
                    sql = "INSERT INTO `mydb`.`logs` (`request_id`) VALUES (%s);"
                    
                    cursor.execute(sql, (request_id))
                    
                    connection.commit()
finally:
    connection.close()
```

Comment: except pymysql.err.IntegrityError: This is how I found the solution!

Comment: You can also use INSERT IGNORE, but that ignores all kind of errors